# Silverlight 4 and System.Runtime.Serialization

Tags: serialization, silverlight-4.0, datacontractserializer

I have a Silverlight 4 project that contains some business objects.  I added a Test project.  One of the tests is to serialize the business objects from the Silverlight project using `DataContractSerializer`.  To reference `DataContractAttribute`, I have to add a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization`.  However, there are different and apparently incompatible versions in the Silverlight runtime and in the .NET 4 Runtime of the Test project.

What's the best strategy to serialize objects in a Silverlight project such that they can be consumed by a standard .NET 4 runtime?

Comment: What is the source of your information regarding incompatiblities?

Comment: @Anthony: The fact that I got a runtime exception in the Test project claiming that System.Runtime.Serialization.dll (Silverlight version) could not be found lead me to notice that the versions available in Silverlight and in .NET 4 are different (Silverlight 4 project shows v2.0.50727, .NET 4 test project shows v4.0.30319)

Comment: Well the __implementation__ for the serlization differs (they run on different runtimes) but the format generated is the same, what would be the point otherwise?

Comment: @Anthony: I totally agree.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this morning that I had added a reference to a Silverlight project from a non-Silverlight project and VS *warned* about that not being a good idea, but still allowed the non-Silverlight project to run.  Because a different version of `System.Runtime.Serialization` was referenced in each project, the unit test aborted with an inability to load that DLL.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose i would use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx). This serializes your business objects to json. It it supported in Silverlight and .NET Framework since 3.5.

An example how to use the serializer can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If your objects allow it (regarding constraints mentioned below), try a serializer such as protobuf-bet or one of the other protocol buffer implementations.

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

They place some constraints on the implementation of your business objects (contracts, rather), for example that null and empty collections are considered equivalent to name one example.